# Colors become distorted randomly in Linux, not in Windows

Tags: linux, display, troubleshooting

Currently running Fedora, but my issue is not exclusively pointed to this distribution!

[image] I have been experiencing this issue of my screen colors inverting/distorting from time to time. And this *bug* is not exclusive to a single Linux distro, as I have experienced this in other distros (in some more and in some less often).

If I snap a screenshot it will not capture the inverted/distorted colors, rather they appear normal (once dealt with an issue through a temporary "solution", which was:

1. To lock the screen, and wait till screen turns off
2. Suspend
3. Close my laptop lid (This however works only with KDE Desktop, not in Gnome Or Cinnamon)
4. Restart / Shutdown

I believe it is not a hardware issue, because after experiencing this *bug* I went back to Windows and did not experience anything of the sort.

My laptop model is HP Elitebook 840 G1 without any discrete/dedicated GPU in my model; verified in BIOS/UEFI.

---

`sudo inxi --verbosity 8 --filter` output:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.6-200.fc35.x86_64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc
  v: 2.37-10.fc35
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,msdos1)/vmlinuz-5.15.6-200.fc35.x86_64
  root=UUID=e88fc516-1afa-4467-af98-bd1837c33b05 ro rootflags=subvol=root
  rhgb quiet
  Console: pty pts/0 wm: gnome-shell DM: GDM 41.0
  Distro: Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP EliteBook 840 G1
  v: A3009DD10203 serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <filter>
  Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 198F v: KBC Version 15.59 serial: <filter>
  BIOS: Hewlett-Packard v: L71 Ver. 01.49 date: 02/24/2020
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 26.5 Wh (89.2%) condition: 29.7/29.7 Wh (100.0%)
  volts: 12.5 min: 11.1 model: Hewlett-Packard Primary type: Li-ion
  serial: <filter> status: Charging
Memory:
  RAM: total: 7.19 GiB used: 2.21 GiB (30.7%)
  Array-1: capacity: 16 GiB slots: 2 EC: None max-module-size: 8 GiB
  note: est.
  Device-1: Bottom-Slot 1(left) size: 4 GiB speed: 1600 MT/s type: DDR3
  detail: synchronous bus-width: 64 bits total: 64 bits
  manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai part-no: HMT351S6EFR8A-PB serial: <filter>
  Device-2: Bottom-Slot 2(right) size: 4 GiB speed: 1600 MT/s type: DDR3
  detail: synchronous bus-width: 64 bits total: 64 bits
  manufacturer: Samsung part-no: M471B5173DB0-YK0 serial: <filter>
PCI Slots:
  Slot: 1 type: 32-bit PCI PCI SLOT1 status: Available length: Long
CPU:
  Info: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-4300U socket: BGA1168 (U3E1)
  note: check bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Haswell family: 6
  model-id: 45 (69) stepping: 1 microcode: 26 cache: L1: 128 KiB
  L2: 512 KiB L3: 3 MiB bogomips: 19953
  Speed: 973 MHz min/max: 800/2900 MHz base/boost: 1900/2500 volts: 0.8 V
  ext-clock: 100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 973 2: 1781 3: 2046 4: 1387
  Flags: abm acpi aes aperfmperf apic arat arch_perfmon avx avx2 bmi1
  bmi2 bts clflush cmov constant_tsc cpuid cpuid_fault cx16 cx8 de ds_cpl
  dtes64 dtherm dts epb ept ept_ad erms est f16c flexpriority flush_l1d
  fma fpu fsgsbase fxsr ht ibpb ibrs ida invpcid invpcid_single lahf_lm
  lm mca mce md_clear mmx monitor movbe msr mtrr nonstop_tsc nopl nx pae
  pat pbe pcid pclmulqdq pdcm pdpe1gb pebs pge pln pni popcnt pse pse36
  pti pts rdrand rdtscp rep_good sdbg sep smep smx ss ssbd sse sse2
  sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 stibp syscall tm tm2 tpr_shadow tsc tsc_adjust
  tsc_deadline_timer vme vmx vnmi vpid x2apic xsave xsaveopt xtopology
  xtpr
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: VMX disabled
  Type: l1tf mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes,
  SMT vulnerable
  Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI
  Type: spec_store_bypass
  mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Type: spectre_v1
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB: conditional,
  IBRS_FW, STIBP: conditional, RSB filling
  Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics vendor: Hewlett-Packard
  driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a16
  class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Cheng Uei Precision Industry (Foxlink) HP HD Webcam type: USB
  driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 2-7:3 chip-ID: 05c8:0369 class-ID: 0e02
  Display: server: X.Org 1.21.1.3 compositor: gnome-shell driver:
  loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1366x768 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 361x203mm (14.2x8.0")
  s-diag: 414mm (16.3")
  Monitor-1: XWAYLAND0 res: 1366x768 hz: 60 dpi: 112
  size: 310x170mm (12.2x6.7") diag: 354mm (13.9")
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
  v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.5 compat-v: 3.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:03.0 chip-ID: 8086:0a0c
  class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: Intel 8 Series HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:9c20
  class-ID: 0403
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.6-200.fc35.x86_64 running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.40 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I218-LM vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: e1000e
  v: kernel port: 3080 bus-ID: 00:19.0 chip-ID: 8086:155a class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus-ID: 02:00.0
  chip-ID: 8086:08b1 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
  IP v4: <filter> type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global
  broadcast: <filter>
  IP v6: <filter> type: noprefixroute scope: link
  WAN IP: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB driver: btusb
  v: 0.8 bus-ID: 2-3.2:4 chip-ID: 8087:07dc class-ID: e001
  Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down
  bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes
  address: see --recommends
Logical:
  Message: No logical block device data found.
RAID:
  Message: No RAID data found.
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 60.77 GiB (13.0%)
  SMART Message: Required tool smartctl not installed. Check --recommends
  ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: HGST (Hitachi)
  model: HTS725050A7E630 size: 465.76 GiB block-size: physical: 4096 B
  logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 7200 serial: <filter>
  rev: B550 temp: 32 C scheme: MBR
  Message: No optical or floppy data found.
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 464.76 GiB size: 464.76 GiB (100.00%)
  used: 60.51 GiB (13.0%) fs: btrfs block-size: 4096 B dev: /dev/sda2
  maj-min: 8:2 label: fedora_localhost-live
  uuid: e88fc516-1afa-4467-af98-bd1837c33b05
  ID-2: /boot raw-size: 1024 MiB size: 973.4 MiB (95.06%)
  used: 268.6 MiB (27.6%) fs: ext4 block-size: 4096 B dev: /dev/sda1
  maj-min: 8:1 label: N/A uuid: cc92cd2f-d0e1-432d-8947-5451608067c9
  ID-3: /home raw-size: 464.76 GiB size: 464.76 GiB (100.00%)
  used: 60.51 GiB (13.0%) fs: btrfs block-size: 4096 B dev: /dev/sda2
  maj-min: 8:2 label: fedora_localhost-live
  uuid: e88fc516-1afa-4467-af98-bd1837c33b05
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache-pressure: 100 (default)
  ID-1: swap-1 type: zram size: 7.19 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: 100
  dev: /dev/zram0
Unmounted:
  Message: No unmounted partitions found.
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: Full speed or root hub ports: 3 rev: 2.0
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-2: 1-1:2 info: Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub ports: 8 rev: 2.0
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 8087:8000 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-3: 2-0:1 info: Hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 9 rev: 2.0
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-4: 2-3:2 info: Microchip (formerly SMSC) Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.1
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 0424:2134 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 2-3.2:4 info: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface
  type: Bluetooth driver: btusb interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s
  power: 100mA chip-ID: 8087:07dc class-ID: e001
  Device-2: 2-7:3
  info: Cheng Uei Precision Industry (Foxlink) HP HD Webcam type: Video
  driver: uvcvideo interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s power: 500mA
  chip-ID: 05c8:0369 class-ID: 0e02
  Hub-5: 3-0:1 info: Super-speed hub ports: 4 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-6: 3-3:2 info: Microchip (formerly SMSC) Hub ports: 4 rev: 3.0
  speed: 5 Gb/s chip-ID: 0424:5534 class-ID: 0900
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 38.0 C mobo: 0.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: note: see --pkg flatpak: 8
  No active dnf repos in: /etc/dnf/dnf.conf
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/_copr_phracek-PyCharm.repo
  1: phracek-PyCharm ~ https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/phracek/PyCharm/fedora-$releasever-$basearch/
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/brave-browser-rpm-release.s3.brave.com_x86_64_.repo
  1: brave-browser-rpm-release.s3.brave.com_x86_64_ ~ https://brave-browser-rpm-release.s3.brave.com/x86_64/
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-cisco-openh264.repo
  1: fedora-cisco-openh264 ~ https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-cisco-openh264-$releasever&arch=$basearch
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-modular.repo
  1: fedora-modular ~ https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-modular-$releasever&arch=$basearch
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates-modular.repo
  1: updates-modular ~ https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-modular-f$releasever&arch=$basearch
  No active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates-testing-modular.repo
  No active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates-testing.repo
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo
  1: updates ~ https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f$releasever&arch=$basearch
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo
  1: fedora ~ https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
  1: google-chrome ~ http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/megasync.repo
  1: MEGAsync ~ https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/Fedora_$releasever/
  No active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
  1: rpmfusion-free-updates ~ https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/metalink?repo=free-fedora-updates-released-$releasever&arch=$basearch
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free.repo
  1: rpmfusion-free ~ https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/metalink?repo=free-fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver.repo
  1: rpmfusion-nonfree-nvidia-driver ~ https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/metalink?repo=nonfree-fedora-nvidia-driver-$releasever&arch=$basearch
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-nonfree-steam.repo
  1: rpmfusion-nonfree-steam ~ https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/metalink?repo=nonfree-fedora-steam-$releasever&arch=$basearch
  No active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-testing.repo
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-nonfree-updates.repo
  1: rpmfusion-nonfree-updates ~ https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/metalink?repo=nonfree-fedora-updates-released-$releasever&arch=$basearch
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-nonfree.repo
  1: rpmfusion-nonfree ~ https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/metalink?repo=nonfree-fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
  Active yum repos in: /etc/yum.repos.d/vscode.repo
  1: code ~ https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode
Processes:
  CPU top: 5 of 260
  1: cpu: 7.4% command: brave pid: 2597 mem: 123.7 MiB (1.6%)
  2: cpu: 5.3% command: brave pid: 2677 mem: 196.4 MiB (2.6%)
  3: cpu: 3.9% command: gnome-shell pid: 1621 mem: 257.4 MiB (3.4%)
  4: cpu: 3.8% command: brave pid: 2500 mem: 305.2 MiB (4.1%)
  5: cpu: 2.0% command: sudo pid: 4836 mem: 9.61 MiB (0.1%)
  Memory top: 5 of 260
  1: mem: 305.2 MiB (4.1%) command: brave pid: 2500 cpu: 3.8%
  2: mem: 291.4 MiB (3.9%) command: packagekitd pid: 1106 cpu: 0.8%
  3: mem: 257.4 MiB (3.4%) command: gnome-shell pid: 1621 cpu: 3.9%
  4: mem: 196.4 MiB (2.6%) command: brave pid: 2677 cpu: 5.3%
  5: mem: 193.5 MiB (2.6%) command: gnome-software pid: 1966 cpu: 0.4%
Info:
  Processes: 260 Uptime: 25m wakeups: 1 Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5
  target: graphical.target tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 11.2.1
  Shell: Bash (sudo) v: 5.1.8 running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.09
```

Notes:

1. Not having any external or other internal disk drives (for testing purposes).
2. [My Reddit post with my video describing my problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/raervc/colors_randomly_become_distorted/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Answer (score 1):

### Original attempt to answer

> If I snap a screenshot it will not capture the inverted/distorted colors, rather they appear normal

This inclines my thinking of recommendation to check your monitor cables and monitor exchange (if we are talking external display) **or** if laptop integrated display, have it repaired in a shop.

Unfortunately for you, neither of these suggestions is cost-free.

---

### Edits section, (anyone can contribute)

You have a [CPU with integrated GPU, formerly Haswell family (Intel® Core™ i5-4300U)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/76308/intel-core-i54300u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-2-90-ghz/specifications.html), and you *should* have also some dedicated GPU, at

GPU #1 snippets:

```
Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics vendor: Hewlett-Packard
...
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
...
```

So, the integrated GPU is Intel HD Graphics 4400 which agrees with your [laptop specs](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03961746#AbT3). But, in the same laptop specs I saw also a dedicated GPU (AMD Radeon HD 8750M) - the OP entered his/her BIOS/UEFI to re-check, but it is not showing there and the OP said this particular model of this laptop did not come with discrete GPU.

### Recommendation

Please try out the live USB below, download, optionally verify ISO, and push it to some blank USB.

Please read the [release notes](https://linuxmint.com/rel_uma_cinnamon.php) before you try the [Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=288).